# OpenDialog for WPF

Tags: c#, fileopendialog

I just started with WPF. Moved from Window Form.

Where do those openDialog, saveDialog gone? And a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Here's the answer to the second question ("And a bunch of stuff"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look in `Microsoft.Win32` namespace

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
{
      ..........
}
```

And the same for `SaveFileDialog`

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
{
      ..........
}
```

Comment: These are hard to set up, in the old Window Form there is easy options, anyway thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the openDialog or the saveDialog always return a value? Otherwise you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: At firs OpenFileDialog should return instance or fail with exception, it is not good practice to check null in this case because you will lost info about exception