# C# get explorer.exe to return a file path

Tags: c#, windows-explorer

In my C# application (using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate) the user needs to select a certain file. I've created a basic file explorer which pretty much works but doesn't look great.

I've been asked to use the standard Windows file Explorer.

I know how to open it:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe");
```

But how can I get a file path returned from it?

Comment: You should use the [`OpenFileDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) instead (assuming you are using WinForms as your GUI library).

Comment: explorer.exe is NOT an open/select file dialog. It lets you WORK with your computer. Use OpenFileDialog instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select a file, the Net Framework provides the OpenFileDialog component.
You can see the reference at [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

But basically, all you have to do is:

Create an Instance of OpenFileDialog

```
using(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
{
```

Set the initial property

```
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
```

Open the control calling the ShowDialog, wait for the OK press from the user and grab the file selected

```
    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileSelected = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

Notice the using statement around the OpenFileDialog(), while not strictly necessary this will assure the Disposing of the dialog

Comment: I would prefer to put this into a `using` block like `using ( var ofd = new OpenFileDialog() ) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered an OpenFileDialog?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I didnt know it existed, thanks.. my searches didnt turn this up

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convince your customer to accept a standard explorer dialogue.
Most likely your customer does not exaclty know what he is asking for.

in WPF you would use something accordingt to this:

> [OpenDialog for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339783/opendialog-for-wpf)

in Froms you would use something accordingt to this:

> http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated because "explorer.exe" is in %PATH% system variable, and executable path is probably not stored anywhere in Windows (in my opinion, maybe im wrong).

"explorer.exe" in all versions of windows i know is located in directory that is defined by %WINDIR% system variable. You can get that variable by method:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()
```

and add string "explorer.exe".

That was simple way.

---

More complicated method:

You can find full path of already running explorer.exe process after by using WMI - little more complicated, but its more correct method.

More information here:
[How to get full path of running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process)